# Explain the mathematical definition of a cryptosystem using words

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, keys

So when googling "cryptosystem" I found a Wikipedia page which contained a mathematical definition of a cryptosystem. Find this definition below.

Could someone tell me what that what the last line means, in words instead of using mathematical signs? Maybe it will help my understanding of it.

> Mathematically, a cryptosystem or encryption scheme can be defined as a tuple $(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{C},\mathcal{K},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{D})$ with the following properties.
>
> 1. $\mathcal{P}$ is a set called the "plaintext space". Its elements are called plaintexts.
> 2. $\mathcal{C}$ is a set called the "ciphertext space". Its elements are called ciphertexts.
> 3. $\mathcal{K}$ is a set called the "key space". Its elements are called keys.
> 4. $\mathcal{E}= \left\lbrace E_k:k\in \mathcal{K}\right\rbrace$ is a set of functions $E_k:\mathcal{P}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. Its elements are called "encryption functions".
> 5. $\mathcal{D} = \left\lbrace D_k:k\in \mathcal{K}\right\rbrace$ is a set of functions $D_k:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}$. Its elements are called "decryption functions".
>
> For each $e\in \mathcal{K}$, there is $d\in \mathcal{K}$ such that $D_d(E_e(p))=p$ for all $p \in\mathcal{P}$.

Comment: "For every encryption key, there's a decryption key"

Comment: ..."and if you apply them both with their respective algorithms you get back what you'd expect: the message for all allowed messages."

Comment: "No matter what key $e$ you choose for encrypting a plaintext $p$, there is some key $d$ (which may or may not be equal to $e$) such that you can decrypt the resulting ciphertext successfully to recover the original plaintext."

Comment: "Every plaintext is associated with a ciphertext by an encryption function that uses key $e$"."Every ciphertext is associated with a plaintext by a decryption function that uses key $d$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct translation would be something like :

> For each key $e$ in the set of keys $\mathcal{K}$, there is a key $d$ also in the set of keys $\mathcal{K}$ such that the decryption function using $d$ as a key, called $D_d$, when applied to the encryption function using $e$ as a key called $E_e$ is the identity function, so that when both are applied in a succession, starting with $E_e$, to a plaintext $p$, one will recover the same plaintext $p$.

So, for each encryption key $e$, there is a decryption key $d$ (possibly the same key) which allows to decrypt the content encrypted using the key $e$.

Comment: I would comment on Lerys wonderfuly explanation but sadly I don't have enough reputation yet. One thing I like to add to Lery is that the definition also includes: [...] for all $p \in\mathcal{P}$. This means that the definition must hold for all plaintext $p$ from the set $\mathcal{P}$. If you find one $p$ that you can encrypt with a given key $e$ and the encryption function $E_e$ but there is no key $d$ to decrypt it back to $p$ with $D_d$ it's no longer a crypto system per definition. Even if it works for all other elements in $\mathcal{P}$.